# Modules not found (unconditional imports):

Tags: python, macos, kivy, executable, py2app

> Hello ! I am trying to generate standalone application of python script for mac os using py2app. But it is giving me following error
>
> Modules not found (unconditional imports):
>
> - ConfigParser (kivy.config, kivy.tools.report)
>
>   - ConfigParser.ConfigParser (numpy.distutils.npy_pkg_config, numpy.distutils.system_info)
>   - ConfigParser.NoOptionError (kivy.config, kivy.tools.report, numpy.distutils.npy_pkg_config)
>   - ConfigParser.RawConfigParser (kivy.config, kivy.tools.report)
>   - Cython (numpy.random._examples.cython.setup)
>   - IPython (IPython.core.pylabtools, IPython.kernel.comm, matplotlib.backends.backend_nbagg)
>   - IPython.core (IPython.core, matplotlib.pyplot)
>   - IPython.core.pylabtools (IPython.core.pylabtools)
>   - IPython.core.pylabtools.backend2gui (IPython.core, matplotlib.backend_bases)
>   - IPython.display (matplotlib.backends.backend_nbagg)
>   - IPython.get_ipython (IPython.core, IPython.display, IPython.kernel, matplotlib.backend_bases)
>   - IPython.kernel (matplotlib.backends.backend_nbagg)
>   - IPython.kernel.comm (matplotlib.backends.backend_nbagg)
>   - Image (docutils.parsers.rst.directives.images, docutils.writers._html_base, kivy.core.image.img_pil)
>   - OpenSSL (urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl)

```
from setuptools import setup

`APP = ['gui.py'] `  


`DATA_FILES = ['main.py','fonts/add.png','fonts/FUTURASTD- 
 BOOK.OTF','fonts/FasterThanST-LETOM.otf','yest.avi']`


`APP_NAME = 'Fast'`

`OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True, 
    'includes':['PyQt5','PyQt5.QtWidgets','kivy','cv2','scipy'],
    'iconfile': 'app.icns',
    'packages': ['kivy','cv2','scipy']
 }`

`setup(
   app=APP,
   data_files=DATA_FILES,
   options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
   setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

`

Comment: We need to see your setup.py file at least.

Comment: @Raphael I have just uploded setup.py.....can you check it

Comment: Its generate .app file but when run it give popup dialouge error "open console" or terminate